# Unable to construct Instance of specified SQLExceptionConverter

Tags: nhibernate

I am new to Nhibernate and I am trying to fix a warning coming in our project but I am not able to understand from which method or class the exception is raising.

```
   WARN - Unable to construct instance of specified SQLExceptionConverter System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at NHibernate.Bytecode.ActivatorObjectsFactory.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at NHibernate.Exceptions.SQLExceptionConverterFactory.ConstructConverter(String converterClassName, IViolatedConstraintNameExtracter violatedConstraintNameExtracter)


config.SetProperty(Environment.SqlExceptionConverter, typeof(SqlException).AssemblyQualifiedName)
```

In the above line of code SqlException is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException.

And I am sure getting the exception from this class only  because I explicitly added below line of code and same exception caught.

```
Environment.BytecodeProvider.ObjectsFactory.CreateInstance(typeof(SqlException));
```

SQLException is not custom class how to handle this error?

Comment: Could you please let me know why negative vote for this. It will help me when I am going to ask next question to take care of it